# How to access JSON data from an HTML ID

Tags: jquery, json

I want to check an ID in an HTML element and get the corresponding data in JSON format.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="buddy" id="user1" style="display: block;"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(images/1/hank1.jpg)"></div></div>
    <div class="buddy" id="user2"><div class="avatar" style="display: block; background-image: url(images/1/hank2.jpg)"></div></div> 
</div>
<div id="user_info">
    <div class="name">Hank</div> <div class="age">Age: <span>2</span></div>
    <div class="breed">Chocolate Lab</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var userData = '{"user1":[{"name":"User1","age":"3","breed":"Chocolate Labrador"}],"user2":[{"name":"Josh"}]}';
var user = JSON.parse(userData);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = $('.buddy:visible').attr('id');

    $('#user_info .name').text(user.user1[0].name);
    $('#user_info .age span').text(user.user1[0].age);
    $('#user_info .breed').text(user.user1[0].breed);
});
```

The above JS code works and will return the correct data, but how would I use 'var test' to grab the data. Something like the below, even though it doesn't work.

```
var userData = '{"user1":[{"name":"User1","age":"3","breed":"Chocolate Labrador"}],"user2":[{"name":"Josh"}]}';
var user = JSON.parse(userData);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = $('.buddy:visible').attr('id');

    $('#user_info .name').text(user.test.name);
    $('#user_info .age span').text(user.test.age);
    $('#user_info .breed').text(user.test.breed);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets to index into the object.

*(Edit: Note that I have dropped the arrays from your `userData`, they make no sense.)*

```
var userData = '{"user1":{"name":"User1","age":"3","breed":"Chocolate Labrador"},"user2":{"name":"Josh"}}';
var user = JSON.parse(userData);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $('.buddy:visible').attr('id');

    $('#user_info .name').text(user[id].name);
    $('#user_info .age span').text(user[id].age);
    $('#user_info .breed').text(user[id].breed);
});
```

Comment: user[id] will give you array, not the object. You need to use user[id][0].name or modify userData to make userId value an object rather than an array of objects.

Comment: You are right, that's an oversight. However, I argue that the array makes no sense at this point and  the OP should drop it.